# How to reset/blacken a view in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

- I created a subview in my `viewController` and set it to black background while creating.
- After that some video is rendered on to it and then the video pauses.
- I want to blacken the subview for some time after which some other video will be rendered on it.

**Questions**

So I thought the options to achieve this would probably be to either set a black image on the view  or do something analogous to memset in C++ so that it displays whatever background I had set. Is this understanding/approach correct ?

I was looking at the class reference for UIView in apple documentation but I wasn't able to figure out any property/method which does this. How can this use-case be achived?

Comment: You can also add subviews on UIImageView.

Comment: How do you render videos on your subview? Can you remove that video from the subview and, if needed, set background color back to black?